# apache-tomcat-6.0.30 Socket bind failed/Protocol handler start fail ed

Tags: apache, tomcat

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730013] An attempt was made to access
a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initialize
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.lang.Exception
: Socket bind failed: [730013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way f
orbidden by its access permissions.

INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730013] An attempt was made to access
a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
SEVERE: Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start fail
ed: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730013] An attempt was made to acc
ess a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

The error shows while run apache-tomcat-6.0.30.

Comment: what port are you trying to use?  Is something else already running on that port?

Comment: <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="443" /> 
Not sure any other instance which share the port. How can I find the other resources which uses the same port? thx

Comment: Are there any other configured web servers (apache, IIS)?

Comment: had IIS server. It was de-configured but still 80 port is using by some other process. changed port number to 8080 and now its fine, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process can't use privileged ports by default. Use a port above 1024. If you want to access Tomcat via port 80 use iptables or similar to map port 80 to 8080 or use the supplied service wrapper (jsvc) that will start as root, bind to port 80 and then drop to a non-privileged user.

Comment: mapped port number to 8080 instead of 80 and the website shown up. thanks you!

Comment: it is right, using port 80 and 466 not worked, till I not changed it to higher of 1024 port number.